# variable works with PHP but not with HTML

Tags: php, html, sql

When I write the code below substituting the value in the SELECT statement with a variable all works fine.But then when I create a html from and create a List Box(for this purpose only placing one name in it) the code doesn't work.(please sea the second block of code.Can anyone see why this is.Its giving me a bit of a numb brain as I am new to all of this:)

CODE BLOCK 1

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("names") or die(mysql_error()); 

$aa ="Rose"; 

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name ='$aa'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("names") or die(mysql_error());
$aa = "Rose";
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name ='$aa'") or die(mysql_error());
Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    Print "<tr>";
    Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>" . $info['name'] . "</td> ";
}

Print "</table>";
?>
```

---

CODE BLOCK 2(for simplicity here I have only one item in the option box)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
    <body>
        <FORM name = "topform" method = "POST" ACTION = "tablecreate3.php">
            <select name = "author">
                <option value="Rose">rose</option>
            </select>
        </FORM>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("names") or die(mysql_error());
$aa = "Rose";
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freinds2 WHERE name ='$aa'") or die(mysql_error());
Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    Print "<tr>";
    Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>" . $info['name'] . "</td> ";
}

Print "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the file's extension in which the html form is found. i.e what is its name?

Comment: change `$aa =$_POST["Rose"]; ` to `$aa =$_POST["author"];`

Comment: Hi tried changing to author but still the same problem thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use $_POST you need to use as key name of input element from HTML, . Additionally if you want to Select Date based on data posted by form, you need to check if field was set by surrounding code by this statement if(isset($_POST['author']))

Comment: Hi.I thought using post was compulsory  is there another way around this.Thanks Jim

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like 1. end of html is wrong: < / html>> ?? and 2. You ended the HTML and then you're creating a table. Don't you want to do that while still inside the BODY?